# tikzpicture with 4 curves needs adjustment

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-graphdrawing

I would like to replicate the image below (see "Desired output") because it's too murky + I would like to change the labels.

I would appreciate any help that get's me closer to the goal.

**Current code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:3,scale=1.6,thick]
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   %allows coordinate calculations.

%Define linear parameters for marginal revenue and demand
\def\dintone{5.5}          %Y-intercept for DEMAND_1.
\def\dslpone{-1}         %Slope for DEMAND_1.
\def\mintone{4.5}          %Y-intercept for MR_1.
\def\mslpone{-1.5}          %Slope for MR_1.

\def\dinttwo{2.5}          %Y-intercept for DEMAND_2.
\def\dslptwo{-0.4}         %Slope for DEMAND_2.
\def\minttwo{2}          %Y-intercept for MR_2.
\def\mslptwo{-0.6}          %Slope for MR_2.

\def\pmc{1}           %marginal cost

\def\demandone{\x,{\dslpone*\x+\dintone}}
\def\marginalrevenueone{\x,{\mslpone*\x+\mintone}}

\def\demandtwo{\x,{\dslptwo*\x+\dinttwo}}
\def\marginalrevenuetwo{\x,{\mslptwo*\x+\minttwo}}

% Define coordinates for D_1 and MR_1.
    \coordinate (ints) at ({(\mintone-\dintone)/(\dslpone-\mslpone)},{(\mintone-\dintone)/(\dslpone-\mslpone)*\mslpone+\mintone});
    \coordinate (ep) at  (0,{(\mintone-\dintone)/(\dslpone-\mslpone)*\mslpone+\mintone});
    \coordinate (eq) at  ({(\mintone-\dintone)/(\dslpone-\mslpone)},0);
    \coordinate (dintone) at (0,{\dintone});
    \coordinate (mintone) at (0,{\mintone});
    \coordinate (pfqone) at  ({(\pmc-\dintone)/(\dslpone)},0);
    \coordinate (pfpone) at  ({(\pmc-\dintone)/(\dslpone)},{\pmc});
    \coordinate (mfqone) at  ({(\pmc-\mintone)/(\mslpone)},0);
    \coordinate (mfpone) at  ({(\pmc-\mintone)/(\mslpone)},{\pmc});

% Define coordinates for D_2 and MR_2.
    \coordinate (ints) at ({(\minttwo-\dinttwo)/(\dslptwo-\mslptwo)},{(\minttwo-\dinttwo)/(\dslptwo-\mslptwo)*\mslptwo+\minttwo});
    \coordinate (ep) at  (0,{(\minttwo-\dinttwo)/(\dslptwo-\mslptwo)*\mslptwo+\minttwo});
    \coordinate (eq) at  ({(\minttwo-\dinttwo)/(\dslptwo-\mslptwo)},0);
    \coordinate (dinttwo) at (0,{\dinttwo});
    \coordinate (minttwo) at (0,{\minttwo});
    \coordinate (pfqtwo) at  ({(\pmc-\dinttwo)/(\dslptwo)},0);
    \coordinate (pfptwo) at  ({(\pmc-\dinttwo)/(\dslptwo)},{\pmc});
    \coordinate (mfqtwo) at  ({(\pmc-\minttwo)/(\mslptwo)},0);
    \coordinate (mfptwo) at  ({(\pmc-\minttwo)/(\mslptwo)},{\pmc});    

% DEMAND_1
    \draw[thick,color=blue] plot (\demandone) node[right] {$D_1$};

% MARGINAL REVENUE_1
    \draw[thick,color=blue] plot (\marginalrevenueone) node[right] {$MR_1$};

% DEMAND_2
    \draw[thick,color=black] plot (\demandtwo) node[right] {$D_2$};    

% MARGINAL REVENUE_2
    \draw[thick,color=black] plot (\marginalrevenuetwo) node[right] {$MR_2$};    

% Draw axes, and dotted equilibrium lines.
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$Q$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[above] {$P$};

%MC
    \draw[solid,color=red] plot (\x,{\pmc}) node[right] {$MC$};
    \draw[dashed] (mfpone) -- (mfqone) node[below] {$Q_1$};
    \draw[dashed] (mfptwo) -- (mfqtwo) node[below] {$Q_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Current output**

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The plots you've defined are obviously not the ones in your target image, so obviously the result looks different. What exactly are you trying to change? I assume that you don't want to change the functions you are plotting because those presumably represent whatever it is you are trying to show. So what exactly?

Comment: I want to highlight/color certain areas and add different labels in a later stage, but first I need to replicate the curves in "Desired output". Currently, don't know how to "detach" the curves from the P-axis

Comment: `\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (-1,6) node[above] {$P$};`? But it won't exactly be the P axis then. Not in the usual sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must confess that your code is beyond my ability of comprehension ...

So I only redraw provided images:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that it can be easy to extend/adopt to your demands. Straight lines can be replaced with curves with `plot` macros if necessary. MWE for above picture is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}   %allows coordinate calculations.

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:3,scale=1.6,thick]
% coordinates path with intersections
\coordinate (O)     at  (0,0);
\coordinate (MR_1a) at (0.5,5.5);
\coordinate (MR_1b) at (3,1);
% coordinate axes
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (9,0)  node[right] {$Q$};
\draw[->]   (O) -- + (0,6)  node[above] {$P$};
% line AC=MC
\draw[line width=1mm, purple, name path=A]
    (0,3) -- + (7.7,0) node[right] {$AC=MC$};
% line MR_1
\draw[line width=0.8mm, cyan, name path=B]
    (MR_1a) -- (MR_1b) node[below] {$MR_1$};
% line D_1 - AR_1
\draw[line width=0.8mm, cyan, name path=C]
    (1,5.7) -- (5,1.5) node[below] {$D_1-AR_1$};
% line MR_2
\draw[line width=0.8mm, cyan, name path=D]
    (1.5,4.5) -- (7,2) node[right] {$MR_2$};
% line D_2-MR_22
\draw[line width=0.8mm, cyan, name path=E]
    (2,5) -- (7.7,4) node[right] {$D_2-MR_2$};
% coordinates of intersection with path A 
\path [name intersections={of = A and B, by={c1}}] (c1) circle (1mm);
\path [name intersections={of = A and C, by={c2}}] (c2) circle (1mm);
% not drawn paths for determining intersections
\path[name path=F]   (c1) -- + (0,3);
\path[name path=G]   (c2) -- + (0,3);
% intersections
\path [name intersections={of = F and D, by={c3}}];
\path [name intersections={of = G and E, by={c4}}];
% dashed lines
\draw[dashed] 
    (c2 |- O) node[below] {$Q_1$} -- (c4) -- (c4 -| O) node[left] {$P_1$}
    (c1 |- O) node[below] {$Q_2$} -- (c3) -- (c3 -| O) node[left] {$P_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right. It is unnecessarily complicated. Thx! Used this source for inspiration: https://thetarzan.wordpress.com/category/tikz-for-economists/

Comment: Hm, nice source, however very different to my approach to use of TikZ :-(. I don't like its intensive use of `\def`. For definitions of function TikZ anticipate different approach. For further comments I need more time ... and test all examples. Some of them are very interesting and will test them in spare time :-)